# Unity: 2D character floating using BoxCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to unity and I set up a simple scene with my character and the ground. I added a `Rigidbody2D` and a `BoxCollider2D` to the character and another `BoxCollider2D` to the ground. The boundaries of the Colliders fit the boundaries of the character / ground exactly, but my character is not falling on to the ground, when I hit play, but rather stops and floats a few pixels above it.

I've seen a lot of similar questions but the solutions didn't work for me (or maybe I didn't understand them right, as I mentioned above I'm new to Unity and thats my first game).

That's what the floating looks like:

[image]

I could obviously "fix" this by lowering the upper boundary below the actual boundary of the ground, like this:

[image]

But that's obviously not a good solution and I'd still like to know what is causing this bug and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe gap has size of [Default Contact Offset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html):

> Set a proximity distance value for colliders to be considered in contact, even they are not actually in contact. Colliders whose distance is less than the sum of their contactOffset values generate contacts. This allows the collision detection system to predictively enforce the contact constraint even when the objects are slightly separated.
> Caution: Reducing this value too far could cripple Unity’s ability to calculate continuous polygon collisions. Conversely, increasing the value too much could create artifacts for vertex collision.

You can find it in Edit > Project Settings > Physics2d .

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!